# EC2 instances of ElasticBeanstalk are not retrieving the .env variables set in the Beanstalk console for Laravel application in terminal/ ssh

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying a Laravel application to the ElasticBeanstalk. Now, I am trying to SSH into the EC2 instance of my Beanstalk environment and run a command.

```
php artisan migrate --force
```

But I cannot run it. The command is failing because it is not getting the environment variables set in the Beanstalk Environment. Here is what I did.

I ssh into the instance. Then I go to the /var/www/html folder. Then I run the "php artisan migrate --force" command. As I mentioned it is failing because it is not getting the database credentials set in the Beanstalk environment. I also tried this.

```
sudo -u root php artisan migrate --force
```

The same thing happened. I also played around with tinker in the terminal. When I retrieve the app name like env('APP_NAME'), it is returning null. What is the issue and how can I fix it?

Comment: I recently faced this... It took a while to resolve it with support and the EB service team but in the end it was because my env variables contained special characters which broke the deploy scripts at the point where envvars were being copied to the instance; if your envvars have special characters you’ll need to change them (at least we did).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> The command is failing because it is not getting the environment variables set in the Beanstalk Environment.

On **Amazon Linux 2** (AL2), the EB env variables are stored in `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env`. Thus when you ssh to your EB instance,  you can use the following to populate your env variables (need to sudo to root firs):

```
sudo su 
export $(cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env | xargs)
echo $YOU_ENV_NAME_FORM_EB
```

This is **undocumented** way of doing this on AL2.

Note:

The env variables shouldn't have **spaces**. Also the file is **not immediately available**. It gets created when deployment succeeds.

Comment: You're the legend! You saved my life. I was writing 24 variable by hand :D